# Can I create new repository on github.com by shell command?

Tags: git, github, github-api

Now If I want to create a new repository on github.com, I have to create it on the website github.com. So can I create a new one just on my local machine by shell command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several CLI tools for Github. One of the more famous is [`hub`](https://hub.github.com/), written in Go. This is how you would remotely create a new Github repo from your shell with it:

```
$ git init
$ git add . && git commit -m "It begins."
$ git create -d "Description goes here"
# (creates a new project on GitHub with the name of current directory)
$ git push origin master
```